# JavaFX ListView selection - how to delete the selection border

Tags: listview, javafx

I have a javaFX ListView with a setCellFactory in order to customize the cells. The problem is that when I select a cell a blue border appear around the cell. Where is this border coming from ? I would like to change the background color of the cell instead of using a blue border.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border is coming from the default stylesheet, [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css); see lines 2233-2242 (in Java 8; in prior versions it was caspian.css). These borders are implemented by having nested background colors with varying insets.

To remove the border, try the following in an external stylesheet:

```
.list-cell:filled:selected {
  -fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
  -fx-background-insets: 0 ;
}
```